# Why is my output not printing with the correct values?

Tags: c++

Our professor has asked us to make a program in which the user is building their own pizza, but I have encountered some problems with my output. Before I modularized everything and cleaned up the main function the project was working fine but as soon as I built some functions in order to clean up the code, I ran into some problems that I can't figure out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string nameinput(string name);
double pizzasize2(int pizzasize);
char pizzacrust(char pizzatype);
int pizzatoppings(double totaltoppings);
void showreceipt();

// PART TWO

double totaltoppings,
       totalprice,
       tax;
int pizzasize;

const double topping = 1.25;
string name;
bool discount = false;
char pizzatype;

string name1;
int size,
       crust,
       toppings,
       receipt;


int main( )
{


    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    name1 = nameinput(name);
    size = pizzasize2(pizzasize);
    crust = pizzacrust(pizzatype);
    toppings = pizzatoppings(totaltoppings);
    showreceipt();

}

string nameinput(string name)
{

    cout << "Welcome to Sevag and Aleksei's Pizzeria." << endl;
    cout << "Enter your first name: ";      // Grab users first name.
    cin >> name;
    return name;
}
double pizzasize2(int pizzasize)
{
    double pizzaprice;

    cout << "Pizza Size:        Cost:   \n";    // Menu being displayed.
    cout << " 10 inches     $10.99  \n";
    cout << " 12 inches     $12.99  \n";
    cout << " 14 inches     $14.99  \n";
    cout << " 16 inches     $16.99  \n";

    cout << "What type of pizza would you like?\n"          // Ask for desired size of pizza.
         << "10, 12, 14, or 16 (Enter the number only): ";
    cin >> pizzasize;

    switch (pizzasize)      // Set of switch statements that displays the price of the desired pizza size.
    {
    case 10:
        pizzaprice = 10.99;
        break;

    case 12:
        pizzaprice = 12.99;
        break;

    case 14:
        pizzaprice = 14.99;
        break;

    case 16:
        pizzaprice = 16.99;
        break;

        default:
        cout << "That is not a valid size" << endl;;
    }
    return pizzasize;
}
char pizzacrust(char pizzatype)
{
    //char pizzatype;

    cout << "What type of crust do you want?\n"     // Ask for desired type of pizza.
             << "(H) Hand Tossed\n"
             << "(T) Thin Crust\n"
             << "(D) Deep Dish\n"
             << "Enter H, T, or D: ";
    cin >> pizzatype;
    cout << "All pizzas come with cheese.\n";

    switch (pizzatype)  // Set of switch statements that prints out the desired crust instead of displaying one letter.
    {
    case 'H':
    case 'h':
        cout << "Hand-Tossed Crust" << endl;
        break;

    case 'T':
    case 't':
        cout << "Thin-Crust" << endl;
        break;

    case 'D':
    case 'd':
        cout << "Deep-Dish" << endl;
        break;

    default:
    cout << "That is not one of the choices. Hand-Tossed Crust will be used instead." << endl;
    }
    return pizzatype;
}
int pizzatoppings(double totaltoppings)
{
    char pepperoni,
    sausauge,
    onion,
    mushroom;


    cout << "Additional toppings are $1.25 each, choose from: \n"       // Ask for desired toppings.
         << "Pepperoni, Sausauge, Onion, Mushroom.\n";
    cout << "Do you want Pepperoni? (Y/N): \n";
    cin >> pepperoni;
    cout << "Do you want Sausage? (Y/N): \n";
    cin >> sausauge;
    cout << "Do you want Onions? (Y/N) \n";
    cin >> onion;
    cout << "Do you want Mushroom? (Y/N) \n";
    cin >> mushroom;

    if ((pepperoni == 'Y') || (pepperoni == 'y'))   // Set of if-else statements that takes number of toppings wanted by the user.
        {
            totaltoppings += 1;
        }
    else
        {
            totaltoppings += 0;
        }
    if ((sausauge == 'Y') || (sausauge == 'y'))
        {
            totaltoppings += 1;
        }
    else
        {
            totaltoppings += 0;
        }
    if ((onion == 'Y') || (onion == 'y'))
        {
            totaltoppings += 1;
        }
    else
        {
            totaltoppings += 0;
        }
    if ((mushroom == 'Y') || (mushroom == 'y'))
        {
            totaltoppings += 1;
        }
    else
        {
            totaltoppings += 0;
        }
    return totaltoppings;
}
void showreceipt()
{
    cout << "Your order is as follows:" << endl;    // Display the users order
    cout << pizzasize << "-inch pizza";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "You chose " << totaltoppings << " toppings.\n";

    if ((name == "Sevag") || (name == "sevag")|| (name == "aleksei") || (name == "Aleksei"))    // Checks whether user name matches pizzeria owner names.
        {
            discount = true;
            cout << "You are eligible for a $2 discount!" << endl;
        }

    if (discount == true)   // Checks whether discount is true or not in order to apply discount.
        {
            totalprice -= 2.0;
        }

    totalprice = pizzasize + (topping * totaltoppings); // Displays the users final total.
    tax = totalprice * .10;
    cout << "Your subtotal is: $" << totalprice << endl;
    totalprice += tax;
    cout << "Tax is: $" << tax << endl;
    cout << "Your total price is $" << totalprice << endl;
    cout << name << ", your order will be ready for pickup in 30 minutes.";
}
```

Heres the output:

```
Welcome to Sevag and Aleksei's Pizzeria.
Enter your first name: John
Pizza Size:         Cost:   
 10 inches      $10.99  
 12 inches      $12.99  
 14 inches      $14.99  
 16 inches      $16.99  
What type of pizza would you like?
10, 12, 14, or 16 (Enter the number only): 14
What type of crust do you want?
(H) Hand Tossed
(T) Thin Crust
(D) Deep Dish
Enter H, T, or D: H
All pizzas come with cheese.
Hand-Tossed Crust
Additional toppings are $1.25 each, choose from: 
Pepperoni, Sausauge, Onion, Mushroom.
Do you want Pepperoni? (Y/N): 
y
Do you want Sausage? (Y/N): 
y
Do you want Onions? (Y/N) 
y
Do you want Mushroom? (Y/N) 
y
Your order is as follows:
0-inch pizza
You chose 0.00 toppings.
Your subtotal is: $0.00
Tax is: $0.00
Your total price is $0.00
, your order will be ready for pickup in 30 minutes.
```

My receipt function should be printing out with the values the user inputted but it wont. How can I fix this?

Comment: What did you observe when debugging your code line by line, where these values changed unexpectedly?

Comment: Note: If your compiler was up to date this code might not compile. `using namespace std;` causes a collision between `int size,` and the `std::size` function added in C++17. Be careful with this because it really sucks when you hand in homework that works on your PC but doesn't on the marker's.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem into a [mre]. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Also worth noting that global variables can be areal kick in the teeth by themselves.  Since any function can change a global variable at any time, you always have to keep a eye out for unadvertised side effects.

Comment: in main your change `name1` and it print `name` in the `showreceipt`

Comment: Conversion from `double` to `int` certainly isn't going to be doing you any favors. And this *seriously* needs global variable excising.

Comment: You seem to have and use multiple variables to represent the same thing. This is often risky. I can see at least one place in the code where you set one of these variables and then read from the other.

Comment: Recommendation: You can improve on the names you are using vor variables and functions. A good variable name describes what the variable holds and provides hints about how it should be used. `size` is too generic a name. The `pizzasize` variable has a much better name. A function should describe what it does `pizzasize2` doesn't, but if it was `calculatepizzasize` or even `calcpizzasize` it takes a special breed of idiocy to not have a good idea about the purpose of the function and what results to expect when you see it being called.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code

## globals

It's good practice to avoid them. Your code use global as output or arguments of the functions instead of just return a value or get arguments.
You mix the globals and input. That one of the reasons why your code does not work

example:
it better for `showreceipt` to get `name, pizzaSize, crust, toppings` as arguments

## local variables

You can make a local variable inside a function. Instead of that you get arguments that used like a variable

Example: in `nameinput` you don't need `stringname` as an argument, just make a variables `returnName` instead inside the function

## name

Your code does not follow C++ naming conventions and used the name `size` of `std` as a variable (many don't like to use `using namespace std`)

Also `totaltoppings += 0;`s inside `pizzatoppings` does nothing.

fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string nameinput();
double pizzasize2();
char pizzacrust();
int pizzatoppings();
void showreceipt(string name,
    double pizzaSize,
    char crust,
    int toppingsNum);

const double toppingPrice = 1.25;

// PART TWO

int main()
{
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    string name = nameinput();
    double pizzaSize = pizzasize2();
    char crust = pizzacrust();
    int toppings = pizzatoppings();
    showreceipt(name, pizzaSize, crust, toppings);
}

string nameinput()
{
    string returnName;
    cout << "Welcome to Sevag and Aleksei's Pizzeria." << endl;
    cout << "Enter your first name: ";      // Grab users first name.
    cin >> returnName;
    return returnName;
}
double pizzasize2()
{
    double pizzaprice;

    cout << "Pizza Size:        Cost:   \n";    // Menu being displayed.
    cout << " 10 inches     $10.99  \n";
    cout << " 12 inches     $12.99  \n";
    cout << " 14 inches     $14.99  \n";
    cout << " 16 inches     $16.99  \n";

    cout << "What type of pizza would you like?\n"          // Ask for desired size of pizza.
        << "10, 12, 14, or 16 (Enter the number only): ";
    int pizzasize;
    cin >> pizzasize;

    switch (pizzasize)      // Set of switch statements that displays the price of the desired pizza size.
    {
    case 10:
        pizzaprice = 10.99;
        break;

    case 12:
        pizzaprice = 12.99;
        break;

    case 14:
        pizzaprice = 14.99;
        break;

    case 16:
        pizzaprice = 16.99;
        break;

    default:
        cout << "That is not a valid size" << endl;;
    }
    return pizzaprice;
}
char pizzacrust()
{
    //char pizzatype;
    char pizzatype;
    cout << "What type of crust do you want?\n"     // Ask for desired type of pizza.
        << "(H) Hand Tossed\n"
        << "(T) Thin Crust\n"
        << "(D) Deep Dish\n"
        << "Enter H, T, or D: ";
    cin >> pizzatype;
    cout << "All pizzas come with cheese.\n";

    switch (pizzatype)  // Set of switch statements that prints out the desired crust instead of displaying one letter.
    {
    case 'H':
    case 'h':
        cout << "Hand-Tossed Crust" << endl;
        break;

    case 'T':
    case 't':
        cout << "Thin-Crust" << endl;
        break;

    case 'D':
    case 'd':
        cout << "Deep-Dish" << endl;
        break;

    default:
        cout << "That is not one of the choices. Hand-Tossed Crust will be used instead." << endl;
    }
    return pizzatype;
}
int pizzatoppings()
{
    double totaltoppings = 0;
    char pepperoni,
        sausauge,
        onion,
        mushroom;

    cout << "Additional toppings are $1.25 each, choose from: \n"       // Ask for desired toppings.
        << "Pepperoni, Sausauge, Onion, Mushroom.\n";
    cout << "Do you want Pepperoni? (Y/N): \n";
    cin >> pepperoni;
    cout << "Do you want Sausage? (Y/N): \n";
    cin >> sausauge;
    cout << "Do you want Onions? (Y/N) \n";
    cin >> onion;
    cout << "Do you want Mushroom? (Y/N) \n";
    cin >> mushroom;

    if ((pepperoni == 'Y') || (pepperoni == 'y'))   // Set of if-else statements that takes number of toppings wanted by the user.
    {
        totaltoppings += 1;
    }
    if ((sausauge == 'Y') || (sausauge == 'y'))
    {
        totaltoppings += 1;
    }
    if ((onion == 'Y') || (onion == 'y'))
    {
        totaltoppings += 1;
    }
    if ((mushroom == 'Y') || (mushroom == 'y'))
    {
        totaltoppings += 1;
    }
    return totaltoppings;
}
void showreceipt(string name,
    double pizzaSize,
    char crust,
    int toppingsNum)
{
    double totalprice = 0.0;
    bool discount = false;
    cout << "Your order is as follows:" << endl;    // Display the users order
    cout << pizzaSize << "-inch pizza";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "You chose " << toppingsNum << " toppings.\n";

    if ((name == "Sevag") || (name == "sevag") || (name == "aleksei") || (name == "Aleksei"))    // Checks whether user name matches pizzeria owner names.
    {
        discount = true;
        cout << "You are eligible for a $2 discount!" << endl;
    }

    if (discount == true)   // Checks whether discount is true or not in order to apply discount.
    {
        totalprice -= 2.0;
    }

    totalprice = pizzaSize + (toppingsNum * toppingPrice); // Displays the users final total.
    bool tax = totalprice * .10;
    cout << "Your subtotal is: $" << totalprice << endl;
    totalprice += tax;
    cout << "Tax is: $" << tax << endl;
    cout << "Your total price is $" << totalprice << endl;
    cout << name << ", your order will be ready for pickup in 30 minutes.";
}
```

output:

```
Welcome to Sevag and Aleksei's Pizzeria.
Enter your first name: Jacob
Pizza Size:        Cost:
 10 inches     $10.99
 12 inches     $12.99
 14 inches     $14.99
 16 inches     $16.99
What type of pizza would you like?
10, 12, 14, or 16 (Enter the number only): 14
What type of crust do you want?
(H) Hand Tossed
(T) Thin Crust
(D) Deep Dish
Enter H, T, or D: H
All pizzas come with cheese.
Hand-Tossed Crust
Additional toppings are $1.25 each, choose from:
Pepperoni, Sausauge, Onion, Mushroom.
Do you want Pepperoni? (Y/N):
y
Do you want Sausage? (Y/N):
y
Do you want Onions? (Y/N)
y
Do you want Mushroom? (Y/N)
y
Your order is as follows:
14.99-inch pizza
You chose 4 toppings.
Your subtotal is: $19.99
Tax is: $1
Your total price is $20.99
```

Comment: I will add what I changed in a moment